# Get all array value then set it to foreach function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an foreach function below:

```
foreach ($agg as $dep => $emails)
{
    $result[] = [
        'DEPARTMENTID_FK' => $dep,
        'to' => implode(',', $emails),
    ];
}

echo $to = $result[0]['to'];

$host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $port = '587';
    $username = 'donotreply@test.com;
    $password = 'sw0052?';

    $headers = array(
     'Port'          => $port,
     'From'          => $from,
     'To'            => $to,
     'Subject'       => $subject,
    'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    );

    $recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
     array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
       echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
       echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

Now how can I get all the value of `$to`?

For now I need to manually edit this `$result[0]['to']` to be `$result[1]['to']` to see another data.

I want to get it on the loop. Is it possible?

So if there are 3 data, it will run another query 3 times on foreach.

using print_r

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [DEPARTMENTID_FK] => DP0023 [to] => alwis.david@gmail.com,alwis.david@live.com ) [1] => Array ( [DEPARTMENTID_FK] => DP0026 [to] => david.alwis@siix.com.sg ) )
```

Comment: Can you var dump the array so we can see what it looks like? I'm a bit confused why you try $result**[0]**['to']

Comment: Hi @Andreas please see my updated post

Comment: That is the $agg array? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean, as you can see on print_r result that DP0023 have an email address: alwis.david@gmail.com, alwis.david@live.com and DP0026 have an email address: david.alwis@siix.com.sg. I need to set email function there, so email function will send 2 times to that 2 departments.

Comment: So you need to extract data from the array not build an array? Your question has code to build an array. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, sometimes have an array. Because not all department have more than 1 email. So that I need it to be array (multiple email). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// version 1
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo $item['to'];
}


// version 2
$dep_id = '1';
foreach ($result as $item) { 
    if ($dep_id == $item['DEPARTMENTID_FK']) {
        echo $item['to'];
        break;
    }
}

// version 3
foreach ($agg as $dep => $emails)
{
    $result[$dep] = [
        'DEPARTMENTID_FK' => $dep,
        'to' => implode(',', $emails),
    ];
}    

$dep_id = '7';
echo $result[$dep_id]['to'];

// version 4
foreach ($result as $item) {
    // more code here

    $recipients = $item['to'].", ".$bcc;
    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

    // more code here
}
```

Comment: Actually I have divide that email address based on department. If I use your code all email will be show. What I need is the code run based on department

Comment: Thanks for the update but what I I mean, as you can see on print_r result that DP0023 have an email address: alwis.david@gmail.com, alwis.david@live.com and DP0026 have an email address: david.alwis@siix.com.sg. I need to set email function there, so email function will send 2 times to that 2 departments.

Comment: Wow. Now that we see the answer to this question the quality of the question is apparent. It's a horrible way to formulate a question. @Hidayurie

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Email ids are already there.

You need to just fetch them and `implode()` into a sting.

```
$to = implode($agg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variable to store `to` string and `echo` it in your loop:

```
foreach ($agg as $dep => $emails)
{
    $to = implode(',', $emails);
    $result[] = [
        'DEPARTMENTID_FK' => $dep,
        'to' => $to,
    ];
    echo $to; // print it
}
```

**Update**

```
$toList = [];
foreach ($agg as $dep => $emails) {
    $to = implode(',', $emails);
    $result[] = [
        'DEPARTMENTID_FK' => $dep,
        'to' => $to,
    ];

    $toList[] = $to;
}

$toString = implode(',', $toList);
```

Comment: You can see DP0023  = "alwis.david@gmail.com, alwis.david@live.com" and DP0026 = "david.alwis@siix.com.sg" I just want to send email based on that 2 department. If I'm using your code just now, it will send only 1 time to all email list.

Comment: I really don't understand what you expected :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now what you are trying to do.
Try this;
It will loop through each department and gather all emails.

```
 foreach ($agg as $dep)
{
    $temparr[] = dep['to'];
}
$youremails = implode(",", $temparr);

echo $youremails; // comma separated list.
```